# Trigger function on bot mention - discord.py

Tags: python, function, discord.py, bots

I am currently working on a discord bot using discord.py.
My question is, how can I trigger a function, when I mention the bot. I'm thinking about a if statement, but i don't know, which variables I need to call.

```
if [mention] == [bot id]:
    # Here comes the code
```

The rest of the code is working properly.
Would nice if I can get a code snippet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your on_message event/listener.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if bot.user.mentioned_in(message) and message.mention_everyone is False:
        await ctx.send("The message")
```

The `message.mention_everyone` part prevents the bot to respond to `@everyone` or `@here` and the first if statement prevents from bot responding to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) event to check whether there is a mention in the message or if the whole message is just a mention.
A simple if statement should do the trick

```py
if f"<@!{bot.user.id}>" in message.content:
    ctx.channel.send("You mentioned me!")
```

Comment: First of all, in the `on_message` event there isn't `ctx`, secondly `.send` is a coroutine so it should be awaited. Third of all there's a much better way, the answer from **NerdGuyAhmad** explains it pretty well